# Is it possible to get access to a single google drive file without access to whole drive or using an drive app?

Tags: google-drive-api, picker

In the past I used the old Google Docs API and the Google Picker to have access to one single private file from Google Docs. I've got an access token to get access to that file.

With Google Drive I've to use an Google Drive app to accomplish this but this seems too much workflow in my opinion (install app first then use picker) to get access to a single private Google Drive Docs file.

Is there no easier way to get access to a single private Google Drive Docs file than installing an app or without asking permissions to read the WHOLE Google Drive of a user?

Update: @Izak is working with me on this issue. Allow me to add some details. The real issue is that when you use the drive.file scope, the urls in exportLinks don't work anymore. For our use case, we want to fetch the html representation of the document, so we use the exportLinks feature for that. When using drive.file, and attempting to download the text/html version, the response is a 404 status. If you use drive.readonly, exportLinks work properly. My guess would be that drive.file is not sufficient to use the export facility. Perhaps someone can confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relatively restricted auth scope that only allows per-file access:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

And if you know the file ID, you can retrieve its metadata and contents. More details about the scopes are on https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes

`exportLinks` are being returned for the docs files. If you convert your files during insertion and updating, they will be available. Take a look at the `convert` parameter during insertion: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: That answer does not help me because I'm not uploading documents. I just want to download :/

Comment: @therealmarv, then there is no way. This is actually a hot topic and we think your use case should be addressed.

Comment: Are there any news on that?